# list Model - null, populating list from oracle database java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to set the model by data from Database(sql developer).

```
DefaultListModel m;

public DefaultListModel getModelFromDB()
{
    m = new DefaultListModel();

    try{
      String query = "select * from users";
      PreparedStatement p = con.conn.prepareStatement(query);
      con.rs = p.executeQuery();

      while(con.rs.next())
      {
       String name = con.rs.getString("user_name");
       m.addElement(name);
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return m;
}
```

Why am I getting null in my model "m"?  It is possible to add if add element is written outside the try/catch

Comment: You should not be getting null, since you create an instance of the DefaultListModel. However you may have an "empty" model if the SQL query doesn't work. Don't use `{}` for the catch block. How will you know if there is an error??? You should always print the Exception.

Comment: thanks for the answer. SQL query works fine, as I am using it in other functions. For catch block, it says Null.

Comment: So before you do "return m" do you print out the number of entries in the model? In other words do some basic debugging. We can't debug the code for you because we don't have access to your database or your code.

Comment: oh, yeah I do get that. So 'return m' shows this: m = (javax.swing.DefaultListModel) []

Comment: So it is not null. But that is not what I asked you. I asked you to display the number of items in the model. In other words, did you verify that the SQL query returned data and that the data was added to the model?

Comment: oh, yes I have displayed items in model. But there is nothing. I have tested by putting the 'm.addElement(anyString)' outside try/catch, so it worked.

Comment: `But there is nothing.` - so the problem is your SQL statement is no returning any data. Did you display the value of each "name" in the while loop? I can't offer any more help. You know there are no items in the model so fix the problem.